# Rheem OEM condenser fan motor part number

Tags: air-conditioning

I called Rheem to get the OEM part number for a condenser fan motor that was originally installed in a model number **14AJA36A01** condenser. Here is the tag on the condenser outside the home:

[image]

I would like to purchase the OEM condenser fan motor to install in this condenser. The previous homeowner installed an aftermarket condenser fan motor, so I cannot determine the OEM part number. When I contacted Rheem via telephone, the person who answered said they do not deal with parts and that I had to go through an A/C contractor (utterly useless). Googling the model number yields very few search results. I'm at a loss. Any ideas on how I can determine the part number? I'm thinking I can look for a similar home down the street and pray that they have a similar A/C system, but I doubt any homeowner would appreciate some stranger looking at their A/C unit (so no, not doing that).

Comment: Re: the bounty - How do you tell what the specs would be for a replacement fan motor from a condenser's nameplate?

Comment: Protech is a subsidiary of RHEEM and make their motors.  So you will likely only find the PROTECH label motor.  I believe your part is 51-100999-03.  It would help to have the part number on the motor that is installed for cross reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck on OEM parts for that unit. I've tried to look at this question as to how it would be applicable to anyone's unit. On the nameplate, you're given the horsepower and you know it's 220v; the only question is what RPM it needs to be. I think it's reasonable to assume that if it's a 1/6hp motor, it's not any faster than 1,200 RPM. It is possible that it's even slower though... (that's why I just ask the guy at the store).

---

I'm *reasonably sure* what you'd need if it does fail is a 1/6hp ~1,200 rpm motor. (I don't *think* you can go wrong using a 1/3hp motor.) If whatever's in there ran fine for years, I'd be using a direct replacement of the existing one's specs.

Personally, I never ask for OEM parts (it's not like Rheem winds their own motors anyway). I [get the $100 version and go on with life](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/how-do-i-replace-a-condenser-fan-motor-in-a-central-air-unit?rq=1). I go to the parts store, plop the old one on the table and say gimme. Considering that the OEM motor failed less than nine years into service, why would you bother? :) Just run it into the ground: *Don't fix it if it ain't broke*.

> Six-pole motors run at 1,200 rpm unloaded (7,200 Ã· 6) and between 1,050 and 1,175 rpm loaded. They are often used for air-handling equipment, direct-drive applications, window fans, furnace blowers, room air conditioners, heat pumps, and other equipment where the relatively slower motor speed makes for quieter operation. –*How to Determine Speed for an Ac Induction Motor*, [achrnews.com](http://www.achrnews.com/articles/84983-how-to-determine-speed-for-an-ac-induction-motor)

---

> Example: A 20-inch, 24-degree pitch fan blade operating at 1,140 rpm will require a 1/6 hp motor for proper motor and system performance. That same blade operating at 1,725 rpm will require a 1/2 hp rated motor. The blade is designed to work in both applications; however, the increase in operating speed has a direct impact on the hp requirements. Operating this fan blade at the higher rpm requires a minimum 1/2 hp motor. Less than 1/2 hp will most likely cause the motor to operate in an overload condition. –*Stop Blowing Hot Air*, [achrnews.com](http://www.achrnews.com/articles/82389-stop-blowing-hot-air)